# How to send fixed amount of ether from contract using call function in solidity?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, remix

I am trying to send ether from contract to a wallet, when I use the call function with msg.value it works, however when I try to send 1 ether instead of msg.value it doesn't work. Why is that and how to overcome this? I am using Remix.io Javascript VM London, can that be the reason?

Here this code below works:

```
function sendMoney() public payable  {
    address payable receiver = payable(0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2);

    (bool sent, bytes memory data) = receiver.call{ value: msg.value }("");
    require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
}
```

However this code below doesn't work. I have to send fixed amount of ether.

```
function sendMoney() public payable  {
    address payable receiver = payable(0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2);

    (bool sent, bytes memory data) = receiver.call{ value:  1 ether }("");
    require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sendMoney() public payable  {
    address payable receiver = 
    payable(0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2);

    (bool sent, bytes memory data) = receiver.call{ value:  1 ether }("");
    require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
}
```

This works. You just need to pass something in "value" in remix, and after 1 ether will be transfered to 0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2 and value that you passed in remix will be transfered to contract balance.